# copy json objects to new json objects to be used for different listview items

Tags: android, json

I am writing an android app and need to copy the contents of 1 json object to 4 seperate json objects (depending on which values are stored in the object). how do i do this?

Comment: Look into google gson. I'd make the json into objects and then writte the objects into json.

Comment: I use pure json at the moment. I dont see the need for gson (and adding more repos and more data) to my app. If it is imposible to do this without gson, of course I have no choice.

Answer (score 2):

you have available two different constructor for this purpose take a look to the JSonObject documentation at:

[JsonObject(JSonObject, String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28org.json.JSONObject,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

and

[JSonObject(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: assume that your JSonObject is called yourJsonObj you can do something like JSonObject newJsonObj = new JSonObject(yourJsonObj.toString());